# Why ibeacon only support android 4.3+?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Is that possible to implement iBeacon API for android 4.2 and lower with BLE?

update:

According to davidgyoung, theoretically it's possible to enable ibeacon in BLE enabled devices with android 4.3- only if building up a ibeacon API from bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Bluetooth low energy technology was only added in Android 4.3+.

Prior Android devices also did not had Bluetooth chips capable of BLE (standard v4.0).

So **no**, you cannot make a device without a BLE chip work as a BLE chip (and even if you did, it would make no sense nor use).

Comment: Some devices which run Android version < 4.3 may have BLE hardware.

Comment: @Mighter yes, but very few. And the BLE API was added in Android 4.3, so they still need Android 4.3 to fully work with iBeacons. You need both.

Comment: @shkschneider - a lot of them did.  But without software support in the operating system, or a hole in the security model to roll your own support, you couldn't use it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, you're right. I was summing things up. You need both: Bluetooth 4.0 chip with BLE for the hardware and Android 4.3+ for the software API.

Comment: You need 4.3+ for the Android-standard API people are familiar with now.  But there were other device-specific APIs available earlier.  Also, not all phones with BLE hardware have it connected through to the Android APIs.

Comment: I might not be aware or other libraries that let you use iBeacons prior to Android 4.3. If you know such library, please share :)

Answer (score 1):

Android phones must have both Bluetooth 4.0 hardware and a SDK to detect iBeacons.  Generally this means Android 4.3+ and a phone made in late 2012 or later.

Samsung phones include a proprietary Bluetooth 4.0 SDK for their devices with Bluetooth 4.0 chips and Android versions 4.1 and 4.2.  Devices like the Galaxy S3 shipped with this.

There is no off-the-shelf iBeacon detection library using this SDK, so if you want to detect iBeacons on these devices, you would have to roll your own.

Also, keep in mind that many if not most of these devices are already getting upgrades to Android 4.3, so this is a shrinking pool of devices for which this is possible and necessary.  For non-Samsung devices and Samsung devices manufactured before late 2012, it is not possible at all due to lack of a Bluetooth 4.0 library or Bluetooth 4.0 hardware.